# What is the most modern technique for generating a video from an image+driver video?

Tags: image-generation, deepfakes

NVIDEA's [Maxine and Live Portrait](https://developer.nvidia.com/maxine) microservices look very promising but they are still in early access. But if you dig into Live Portrait it seems to be  built off of a [three year old github repo](https://github.com/NVlabs/imaginaire/blob/master/projects/fs_vid2vid/README.md). Example from the repo:

[image]

Another big one I have found is the [first-order-model](https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model) repo which is a little older and seems to do about the same kind of thing:

[image]

I would think there would be a lot of advancements in the last three years. Are these the best libraries to use if you want something off the shelf? Is there a name for this particular type of technology or class of algorithms?